# Jquery .hide() with html firing only the first time on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form in which I'm hiding and showing fields according to the dropdown selection. Initially, when the button is clicked, only the dropdown selection option is shown and the rest of the fields are hidden. Once the form is saved, the user can add another form. So when I click the button for the second time, the `.hide()`/`.show()` doesn't work. Instead the entire form is displayed. Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#button").click(function () {
        alert("handler called");
        $("#name").hide();

        $("#selection").on('change', function () {
            alert("handler called1");
            if ($("#selection").val() == "day") {
                $("#name").show();
            }

        });
    });
});
```

My HTML is:

```
<div id = "days">
       <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div class="selection" id="selection">
                            <table>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><label>selection</label></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><select class="selection"></select></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>          
                        </div>
                        <div class="name" id="name">
                            <table>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><label>Name</label></td>
                                        <td><input type="text"</input></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
       </table>
 </div>
```

The

```
alert("Handler called");
```

is fired the second time but the .hide() doesnt work.

Comment: This isn't valid HTML markup

Comment: Also, you're seeing the change handler every time you click, which seems weird.

Comment: @DaveNewton Can you elaborate?

Comment: What do you mean by "once the form is **saved**, the user can add another form" - are you posting / reloading the entire page?

Comment: are you not using an IDE. Try sublime

Comment: @JohnIdol yes I am posting the entire page again

Comment: @pal most likely then as the page reloads the dropdown is set to the correct value and 'change' is triggered, so hide() is actually working but show() is happening too right after

Comment: @pal Inside the `#button` click handler you set a click handler for a different element. It's almost certainly not a great way to do whatever it is you're doing. If all you're doing is toggling visibility doing it like this is weird.

Comment: @DaveNewton Would you suggest some alternate way of hiding all the textboxes and showing then only on change of the dropdown value? The form itself appears on click on button. Once the user clicks the button, the dropdown menu appears. Once the choice in the dropdown is made, then the corresponding textboxes in the form appear

Comment: @pal Do almost the same stuff, but don't continually re-assign the click handler?

Comment: Where's the button you call in `$("#button")`? You also have a typo in `<input type="text"</input>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It truly is hard to understand your end result, but after analyzing what you are doing more, i think this is what you want:

HTML:

```
<select id="days_dropdown">
    <option value='0'>select one</option>
    <option value='night'>night</option>
    <option value='day'>day</option>
    <option value='afternoon'>afternoon</option>
</select>
<form id="myForm" style="display:none">
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text">
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#days_dropdown").change(function() {
        if ($(this).val() === "day") {
            $("#myForm").show();
        } else {
            $("#myForm").hide();
        }
    });

    $("#myForm").submit(function() {
        //..your code to save the form info
        $(this).hide();
        $("#days_dropdown").val(0);
        return false;
    });

});
```

Let me know if this is the desired result, and ill explain in more detail your mistakes.

Comment: yes this is what Im trying to do. Seeing your code, I realized that my save function is not within the $(document).ready(function() . I guess that is a mistake.

Comment: many mistakes.. especially in the way you were trying to explain a simple problem. Also why are you using tables for this? Tables should be avoided unless you actually want to display a column/row tabular display. Do you use an IDE? if so which one?

Comment: ah good. Its always good to have a good IDE. ok, well if that solved your problem make sure to accept my answer, unless you have more questions

Answer (score 0):

On

`$("#selection").on('change', function () {`

you select your div with id "selection", not the selection tag. And also you should get value of selected option, not the value of "select" tag
Need to modified some in JS code for proper work:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#button").click(function () {

    $("#name").hide();

    $("select.selection").on('change', function () {
        var sel = this;          
        if (sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value == "day") {
            $("#name").show();
        }

    });
});
});
```

Here is a [FIDDLE](http://sfiddle.net/prhqek0g/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to understand specifically what you are going for, but is this what you are trying to do?

HTML

```
<button id='btn'>Click Me</button>
<div id="days">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div>
                        <table>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><label>selection</label></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <select id="selection">
                                            <option value='something'>1</option>
                                            <option value='day'>2</option>
                                            <option value='something'>3</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>          
                    </div>
                    <div class="name" id="name">
                        <table>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><label>Name</label></td>
                                    <td><input type="text"</input></td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btn").click(function() {
        $("#name").hide();

        $("#selection").on('change', function() {
            if ($("#selection").val() == "day") {
                $("#name").show();
            }

        });
    });
});
```

The problem I initially saw was your `.on('change')` , you were trying to attach this to a `div`, but you want to attach it to the `select` element

Comment: Yes. This is what Im trying to do. The problem is that when I save the form the first time, and I click the button again to add another instance of the form, the
`$("#btn").click(function() {
        $("#name").hide();
//code
});` doesnt work.

Comment: what do you mean by when you say _"when I save the form"_ ?

Comment: are we missing more information? are you dynamically adding these tables with some other button?

Comment: are you there? you need to be more active with your responses and your questions as we are here trying to help you.

Comment: I have a save button with the form which saves the information entered. Once it is saved the user can add information to the same form again. For this, the user has to click the button again

Comment: ok, so where is the `form` in your HTML?, are you not using `form` tags? wheres the "save" button?

Comment: ok, so first you load your page, and the user sees a button called "Add Form". They press the button and a form shows with another button named "Save". They fill out the form's inputs, they click save. Once saved, the form empties all information and hides. When they click "Add Form" again, the form shows with empty fields so that they can save again.. Is this what you are trying to do? You need to give us all the information possible or else how are we suppose to know your end result??

Comment: I provided another answer, check it out